# How can I use one function, which belongs to two objects, for only one objects?

Tags: c#, function, object, monogame

I am writing a c# monogame.
On the map there are two goldmines. The player can collect the gold with the following method:

```
 public static void CollectGold(ObjectFactory.ObjectType type)
 { 

  if (Hud.mCurrentTime >= Hud.mCountDuration)
  {
       Counter++;
       Hud.mCurrentTime -= Hud.mCountDuration
       if (sMaxGold < 10)
       { 
        sMaxGold += 2;
       }
       if (sMaxGold >= 10)
       {
           sMaxGold -= 2;  // or sMaxGold = 10 in earlier version-> same output 
       }
  }
  else if (sMaxGold > 0)
  {
         Hud.mGold += 2;
         sMaxGold -= 2;
  }

 }
```

But for sure, when the player collects gold from goldmine, it is like, he is collecting gold from the other mine as well.
How can I seperate this, that CollectGold only works for the one selected mine.
I can't create CollectGold2 with the same code for the second mine, because one time I want to build a lot of mines in my code. I think there is a better way, than copy and paste the method.

My first idea was, that i can check the mine position, so that the method knows the one mine.
But I don't know how to do it?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a custom class for a mine and make a non-static method there instead of a static one. Then you should just find the mine needed and collect it's gold. Example:

```cs
private class Player
{
    public int GoldBalance = 0;
}

private class Mine
{
    public int GoldAvailable = 10;

    public void Collect(Player player)
    {
        if (GoldAvailable <= 0)
            return;

        player.GoldBalance += GoldAvailable;
        GoldAvailable = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question isn't really answerable in this form; we need more information. For example, how are you representing your mines in code?

However, here are a couple of possible approaches:

1. Move your method to the Mine class (if it exists), so that you call the method something like this:

```
var mine = new Mine();
mine.CollectGold();
```

2. Pass a Mine object, or the id of a mine, to the method, so that the signature would look like this:

```
public static void CollectGold(Mine mine)
```

or

```
public static void CollectGold(int mineId)
```

I have removed the `type` parameter which was unused.

Method 1 is probably preferable but it depends what you're trying to achieve and how complex your application will be.